# Does the following hold: $\sup_{x\in X} \frac{d(x,Y)}{\Vert x \Vert} \leq 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I was thinking about the following inequality and could not come up with either a counterexample or a valid proof... Some help would be highly appreciated! I would like to use this in a proof.

Thanks a lot!

---

Consider $(X,\Vert \cdot\Vert)$ a normed vector space and $Y\subset X$ a subspace.

Does the following hold in general ?

$\sup_{x\in X} \frac{d(x,Y)}{\Vert x \Vert} \leq 1$ where $d(x,Y)=
   \inf_{y\in Y}\Vert(x-y) \Vert $ and $x\neq0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, because, since $0\in Y$ (I presume subspace means linear subspace?), $d(x,Y)\le \lVert x\rVert$ for all $x\in X$. Of course, there should be the caveat that sup should be taken for $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Oh yes right.... thanks a lot! (I've just updated the post to make clear that it's when $X \neq 0$)